# Erlang How to get String from list

Tags: string, list, types, erlang

How can i convert List in String in erlang?

My list view:

> [{{19,59,51},{2011,1,14},"fff"},{{19,59,47},{2011,1,14},"ASDfff"}]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such list?

Comment: And what shoud the string look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple thing would be

```
List = [{{19,59,51},{2011,1,14},"fff"},
        {{19,59,47},{2011,1,14},"ASDfff"}],
IOList = io_lib:format("~w", [List]),
FlatList = lists:flatten(IOList),
```

but as these appear to be timestamps which you may want to be formatted in a better way, something like

```
FormattedIOLists =
   [ io_lib:format("~4..0B-~2..0B-~2..0B ~2..0B:~2..0B:~2..0B ~s",
                   [YYYY,M,D, HH,MM,SS, Comment])
     || {{HH,MM,SS},{YYYY,M,D},Comment} <- List ],
FormattedFlatLists =
   [ lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~4..0B-~2..0B-~2..0B ~2..0B:~2..0B:~2..0B ~s",
                                 [YYYY,M,D, HH,MM,SS, Comment]))
     || {{HH,MM,SS},{YYYY,M,D},Comment} <- List ],
```

could fit your bill better.

For quick and dirty interactive output on the shell,

```
9> [ io:format("~4..0B-~2..0B-~2..0B ~2..0B:~2..0B:~2..0B ~s~n", [YYYY,M,D, HH,MM,SS, Comment]) || {{HH,MM,SS},{YYYY,M,D},Comment} <- List ].                 
2011-01-14 19:59:51 fff
2011-01-14 19:59:47 ASDfff
[ok,ok]
10> lists:foreach(fun({{HH,MM,SS},{YYYY,M,D},Comment}) -> io:format("~4..0B-~2..0B-~2..0B ~2..0B:~2..0B:~2..0B ~s~n", [YYYY,M,D, HH,MM,SS, Comment]) end, List).
2011-01-14 19:59:51 fff
2011-01-14 19:59:47 ASDfff
11>
```

Note that in most cases building recursive lists of lists (iolists) is a much better thing to do than flattening those iolists. Most output functions directly accept iolists for output data, so you gain nothing by flattening the lists before the actualy output happens.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just:

```
 io_lib:format("~w", [[{{19,59,51},{2011,1,14},"fff"},{{19,59,47},{2011,1,14},"ASDfff"}]]).
```